# Number of distinct permutation classes up to multiplication by Clifford elements

Tags: gate-synthesis, clifford-group

#### Question

The number of permutation gates on $n$ qubits is $2^n!$. Define an equivalence relation on these gates by $p_1 \approx p_2$ iff $p_1 = C_L p_2 C_R$ where $p_1, p_2$ are $n$-qubit permutation gates and $C_L, C_R$ denote $n$-qubit Clifford gates. What is the number of equivalence classes (defined by this relation) as a function of the number of qubits? We will denote this function by $\mathcal{P}(n)$.

#### Background

From the discussion here [What are the relations between the permutation group and the Clifford group?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/28594/what-are-the-relations-between-the-permutation-group-and-the-clifford-group), it is clear that all Clifford permutations are affine permutations. I believe a permutation gate is affine iff it can be expressed as a Clifford permutation. If this is true we can put an upper bound on the number of equivalence classes by using results from the mathematics literature see, for example, chapter 4 [here](https://drum.lib.umd.edu/bitstream/handle/1903/9449/Draper_umd_0117E_10256.pdf). The number of affine equivalence classes is given there by $1, 1, 4, 302$ for 1,2,3, and 4 bits, respectively. The number of such classes explodes for more bits, but an algorithm is provided to calculate the number for any $n$. I haven't looked closely at this, but it likely intractable to carry out this algorithm for modest $n$.

This number may be only an upper bound on $\mathcal{P}(n)$ since permutations can be equivalent by Hadamard conjugation.

[image: Toff1]

is in the same equivalence class as [image]

which equals

[image].

Are these permutations affine equivalent as well? If so does $\mathcal{P}(n)$ always reduce to counting affine equivalence classes? An affirmative proof of this would answer my question. Otherwise, the question becomes more interesting.