# Proving that linear reversible boolean functions are permutation functions

Tags: gate-synthesis

The answer to [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/28594/what-are-the-relations-between-the-permutation-group-and-the-clifford-group/28602#28602) begins with a statement of my interest:

> |⟩=|()⟩ where :2→2 is a reversible Boolean function. These are exactly the permutations of bitstrings

Assuming one has to perform $U$ followed by measuring the system. If $f$ is also a permutation function, I am led to think that $U$ can be computed classically, and accordingly re-arrange the measurement bases.

Is this intuition correct?

Notice that the statement regards only $U$; it should stay valid for any input and any measurement.

Comment: Are you asking if a 0-1 matrix is unitary iff it’s a permutation?

Comment: Matrix defining linear reversible boolean functions